# MathSciNet review alert?

Tags: soft-question, mathscinet

Other than reading MathSciNet regularly, is there a way to get notified when one of my papers gets a review on MathSciNet?

Comment: Read Mathscinet regularly perhaps?

Comment: With this attitude, we could also have notifications disabled on SE sites, just everyone should read their questions regularly. Not to mention any RSS feeds.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much more productive for you to have just e-mailed the American Math Society? They designed MathReviews and run MathSciNet, if anyone would know whether such a thing is possible, it would be them.

Comment: Unless you have something like 10 papers or more still pending review, this is nothing like canceling notifications on SE.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

While you could do as @Geoff Robinson suggests and look at MathSciNet regularly, in early 2017, we plan to have email alerts enabled on MathSciNet.  The target is February 2017.

Other new features will be rolled out in January and February.  The first demos will be at the Joint Mathematics Meetings in Atlanta.

Edward Dunne,
Executive Editor,
*Mathematical Reviews*

Comment: Any progress here?

Comment: Let me second @Dmitri and ask if there is any progress on this feature?

Comment: This has been delayed. Now we expect to have it available by August 2018.

Comment: Is it available?

Answer (score 18):

Though only semi-related to the question (couldn't submit it as a comment), I may take the liberty to add that for zbMATH subscribers there is an Atom Feed providing such regular updates for, e.g., subjects or authors. In your case, it would be sufficient to check your author ID at your profile https://zbmath.org/authors/?q=P%C3%A1lv%C3%B6lgyi+D%C3%B6m%C3%B6t%C3%B6r (i.e., Author ID palvolgyi.domotor) - and to use it to subscribe for https://zbmath.org/atom/ai/palvolgyi.domotor
with you favourite news reader.

Olaf Teschke, Managing Editor, zbMATH

Comment: The atom feed seems to be password-protected, so that only Zbmath subscribers can access the page. Won't this be a problem, since most feed aggregators are web-based and access the feeds from their own IP?

Comment: @Federico: that's no different than Mathscinet, isn't it?

Comment: @MartinArgerami That's better than Mathscinet non-existing feature, but still cumbersome to use (and possibly insecure, if it requires giving my Zbmath password to a third-party website). But let's wait for a clarification, maybe I am mistaken.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments! Indeed, the service is currently only available for subscribers. If you feel bad about giving the password to an online aggregator, you could always use an offline newsreader (e.g.,  Thunderbird). If your institution subscribes via IP, you don't need a password at all.